# Save multiple checkbox - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox, laravel-5.4

I need to save multiple checkbox to single field in the database.

```
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="expresion_vegetal_id[]" value="1">Raíz
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="expresion_vegetal_id[]" value="3">tronco
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="expresion_vegetal_id[]" value="4">corteza
                </label>
            </div>
```

Controller:

```
$ficha_tecnica = new Ficha_Tecnica();
$options = $request->get('expresion_vegetal_id');
$ficha_tecnica->expresion_vegetal_id = $options;
$ficha_tecnica->save();
```

this is trying to save, the values ​​in [""], I need only save the numbers

```
insert into `fichas_tecnicas` (`expresion_vegetal_id`) values (["1","3","4"])
```

When I try to save, show the next message

```
1366 Incorrect integer value: '["1","4"]' for column 'expresion_vegetal_id'
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Ficha_Tecnica` nor your database but reading the error message you seem to have a type error.

So either change your database field to an array type or change your array to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You'r cannot add that because 
You can try to loop the expresion_vegetal_id still in array format. 
I see in your question is you need to add that in string format.
You must loop that array first and save one by one or you can used created

I give you the sample using loop. 
You code will looks like this

```
$ficha_tecnica = new Ficha_Tecnica();
foreach ($$request->expresion_vegetal_id as $expresion_vegetal_id) {
    $ficha_tecnica->fresh();
    $ficha_tecnica->expresion_vegetal_id = $expresion_vegetal_id;
    $ficha_tecnica->save();
}
```

i hope you can find the other same way....